# Can I see the progress of a update on a game(fortnite)using my phone?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale, fortnite-save-the-world

I am going to a visit and I started updating fortnite but sometimes my internet crashes and the update stops...so I’d there any possible way to see the progress of the update??

Answer (score 1):

Not unless you can see your own screen. I would suggest downloading Teamviewer on your phone and pc and then check in on your phone to see if your pc has finally finished the update.

See [Teamviewer](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/) and download the free one for your pc and phone
than link them with the code.
and you can control your pc with your phone